# Mac OS: how to map users when mounting disks from another Mac?

Tags: catalina, permission, mount

I have 3 macs and I physically mount my backup disk on one of then and use AFP file sharing to mount the individual folders on the other two machine.  All systems have two users defined (rful011 and russell) but on one system the UIDs are reversed and I believe that this is what is now causing permission problems with the mounted directories.

Prior to Catalina I did not have any problem but now it seems that Mac OS is using the UID to establish permissions rather than the username when accessing shares.  Which is the way NFS works (IIRC).

On the host machine I have shared the directories with both users (and even everyone) but I always get "You do not have  permission to access ..."

I have thought of changing the UID on the one machine that is different but I would rather not -- just too much to go wrong -- I know that Murphy is sitting on my shoulder just waiting to pounce.

Any ideas about how to get the disks mounted with the proper permissions?

Comment: Uid was always the thing to work across machines so I am surprised that it worked. The risk of changing the machine with the wrong ids is much less than anything else

Comment: Are you talking about the [Andrew File System (AFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System), or the [Apple Filing Protocol (AFP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol)? If it’s AFP, it should ignore user names and UIDs, and just map the specific user that authenticated the connection.

Comment: What directory is managing identity for the Macs? Or are you managing the UID by integer number and not using a directory...

Comment: DOH:   AFP, edited...   No directory systems so the UIDs are not consistent  across the machines :(   I have tried to give the user with the same uid in the url but no luck